# Insertar cliente con Volley a una BBDD externa?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

Estoy intentando hacer un insert usando Volley y PHP pero por alguna razón cuando intento registrar en el codigo PHP entra en el else en vez de en el if...

//registrarCliente.php//

```
<?PHP

//hostname, username, password y database
require_once 'db_config.php';

$json=array();

if(isset($_GET["razonsocial"]) && isset($_GET["cif"]) && isset($_GET["dirfiscal"]) && isset($_GET["dirpostal"]) && isset($_GET["poblacion"]) && isset($_GET["codigopostal"]) && isset($_GET["telefono"]) && isset($_GET["mail"]) && isset($_GET["web"]) && isset($_GET["reqfact"]) && isset($_GET["personaresponsable"]) && isset($_GET["nombreentidad"]) && isset($_GET["iban"]) && isset($_GET["idagente"])){

    $razonsocial=$_GET['razonsocial'];
    $cif=$_GET['cif'];
    $dirfiscal=$_GET['dirfiscal'];
    $dirpostal=$_GET['dirpostal'];
    $poblacion=$_GET['poblacion'];
    $codigopostal=$_GET['codigopostal'];
    $telefono=$_GET['telefono'];
    $mail=$_GET['mail'];
    $web=$_GET['web'];
    $reqfact=$_GET['reqfact'];
    $personaresponsable=$_GET['personaresponsable'];
    $nombreentidad=$_GET['nombreentidad'];
    $iban=$_GET['iban'];
    $idagente=$_GET['idagente'];


    $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);

    $insert="INSERT INTO clientes (idcliente, razonsocial, cif, dirfiscal, dirpostal, poblacion, codigopostal, telefono, mail, web, reqfact, personaresponsable, nombreentidad, iban, idagente) VALUES (NULL, '{$razonsocial}','{$cif}','{$dirfiscal}','{$dirpostal}','{$poblacion}','{$codigopostal}','{$telefono}','{$mail}','{$web}','{$reqfact}','{$personaresponsable}','{$nombreentidad}','{$iban}','{$idagente}')";

    $resultado_insert=mysqli_query($conexion,$insert);


}
else{
        $resulta["razonsocial"]='WS No retorna';
        $resulta["cif"]='WS No retorna';
        $resulta["dirfiscal"]='WS No retorna';
        $resulta["dirpostal"]='WS No retorna';
        $resulta["poblacion"]='WS No retorna';
        $resulta["codigopostal"]='WS No retorna';
        $resulta["telefono"]='WS No retorna';
        $resulta["mail"]='WS No retorna';
        $resulta["web"]='WS No retorna';
        $resulta["reqfact"]='WS No retorna';
        $resulta["personaresponsable"]='WS No retorna';
        $resulta["nombreentidad"]='WS No retorna';
        $resulta["iban"]='WS No retorna';
        $resulta["idagente"]='WS No retorna';


        $json['usuario'][]=$resulta;
        echo json_encode($json);
    }

?>
```

Además cuando comento la condición if/else e intento registrar me aparece este error

```
I/ERROR: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Dejo la clase involucrada en android por si acaso

//Fragment registro//

```
public class RegistroClienteFragment extends Fragment implements Response.ErrorListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject> {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private TextView razonSocial;
private TextView CIF;
private TextView dirFiscal;
private TextView dirPostal;
private TextView poblacion;
private TextView codigoPostal;
private TextView telefono;
private TextView mail;
private TextView web;
private Spinner formaPago;
private TextView personaResponsable;
private TextView nombreBanco;
private TextView IBAN;
private Button btnRegistrar;
private Constants constants;
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

ProgressDialog dialog;

// RequestQueue request;
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public RegistroClienteFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment PerfilFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static RegistroClienteFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    RegistroClienteFragment fragment = new RegistroClienteFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registro_cliente, container, false);

    razonSocial = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditRazSoc);
    CIF = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditCIF);
    dirFiscal= (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditDirFis);
    dirPostal = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditDirPos);
    poblacion = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditPob);
    codigoPostal = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditCP);
    telefono = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditTlf);
    mail = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditMail);
    web = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditWeb);
    formaPago = (Spinner) vista.findViewById(R.id.spinnerFormaPago);

    personaResponsable = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditPersResp);
    nombreBanco = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditNomEnt);
    IBAN = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditIBAN);

    btnRegistrar = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrar);

    String[] opciones = {"Pago contado","Giro 15 días","Giro 30 días","Giro 60 días"};
    formaPago.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, opciones));



    btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("ID AGENTE", constants.getIdUsuario()+"| YES");

            insertarCliente();
        }
    });
    return vista;
}

public void insertarCliente(){
    dialog=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    dialog.setMessage("Registrando cliente...");
    dialog.incrementProgressBy(100);
    dialog.show();

    String url="https://alfapharma.000webhostapp.com/registroCliente.php?razonsocial="+razonSocial.getText().toString()
            +"&cif="+CIF.getText().toString()
            +"&dirfiscal="+dirFiscal.getText().toString()
            +"&dirpostal="+dirPostal.getText().toString()
            +"&poblacion="+poblacion.getText().toString()
            +"&codigopostal="+Integer.parseInt(codigoPostal.getText().toString())
            +"&telefono="+Integer.parseInt(telefono.getText().toString())
            +"&mail="+mail.getText().toString()
            +"&web="+web.getText().toString()
            +"&reqfact="+formaPago.getSelectedItem().toString()
            +"&personaresponsable="+personaResponsable.getText().toString()
            +"&nombreentidad="+nombreBanco.getText().toString()
            +"&iban="+IBAN.getText().toString()
            +"&idagente="+constants.getIdUsuario();

    url = url.replace(" ","%20");

    jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,null,this,this);
    // request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

}
// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    dialog.hide();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"El servidor no está disponible, intentalo de nuevo más tarde."+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("ERROR",error.toString());
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    dialog.hide();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"REGISTRO OKEY."+response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Cliente registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

Comment: he cambiado los $_POST por $_GET en el archivo PHP pero ahora me tira otro error

I/ERROR: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: $json['usuario']=$resulta;

Comment: Elimino esa linea ? Comentando el if/else (pero dejando el contenido del if) me salta el mismo error de End of input at character 0 of

Comment: $json['usuario'][]=$resulta; cambialo por la liena anterior

Comment: Sigue lanzandome el mismo error :/

Comment: ¿Tienes un ejemplo de la url POst con todos los parámetros para probar?, el problema es la respuesta de la petición, @Leagueuftrolls

Comment: "he cambiado los $_POST por $_GET " esto no lo debes realizar, se supone que estas definiendo una petición Request.Method.POST, imprime la url

Comment: he estado mirando en la BD y parece ser que estas en lo cierto @Jorgesys llevaba desde que cambie eso esta funcionando correctamente pero volley me lanza un error que no afecta al insert.

Comment: So problema es la petición, debe retornar un objeto json y al parecer no es así...